# Halting of a program the second time around a loop

Tags: c++, mbed

I am trying to use an mbed LPC1768 to interface with a uCAM-III camera module. This requires following a specific transfer of bytes between the mbed and the camera to sync correctly. The datasheet specifies that this can take up to 60 times to happen correctly.

I'm using the library found on this page https://os.mbed.com/users/ms523/notebook/ucam-development/ to help with the syncing process. It doesn't seem to sync correctly though and I get a reponse timeout found in the Get_Reponse function. I added some `printf` to help with debugging and discovered that it will run the sync attempt once, return to the start of the loop, execute the first `printf` statement there but then stop. And I cannot figure out why that is.

This is the response I get on the terminal. Even though there is no code between the `Trying to sync time %i` and `Sending sync chars to uCAM` it doesn't run the 2nd time around the loop and just stops. No more lines are printed after this.

Trying to sync time 0

Sending sync chars to uCAM

Response Timeout

Sync failed - trying again

Trying to sync time 1

```
int uCam::Sync()
{
    // This will give 60 attempts to sync with the uCam module
    for (int i=0; i<60; i++) {

        printf("\n\rTrying to sync time %i ", i);
        // Send out the sync command
        printf("\n\rSending sync chars to uCAM");

        for (int j=0; j<6; j++) {
            _uCam.putc(SYNC[j]);
        }

        // Check if the response was an ACK
        if (Get_Response(_ACK,SYNC[1])) {
            printf("\n\rRecevied ACK");
            // It was an ACK so now get the next response - it should be a sync
            if (Get_Response(_SYNC,0x00)) {
                printf("\n\rGot ACK");
                // We need a small delay (1ms) from receiving the SYNC response and sending an ACK in return
                wait(0.001);
                printf("\n\rSending ACK for ACK");
                for (int k=0; k<6; k++) {
                    _uCam.putc(ACK[k]);
                }
                // Everything is now complete so return true
                printf("\n\rSynced");
                return(1);
            }

        }
        // Wait a while and try again
        printf("\n\rSync failed - trying again");


    }
    printf("\n\rExiting sync function");
    // Something went wrong so return false
    return(0);
}
```